# Using textboxes in a class

Tags: c#, textbox

So for a coding project I need to create an Othello game. Now I'm trying to do most of it on my own. Basically trying to re-learn C#. I'm just trying to create a board. Now I am using textboxes and B represents black and W represents a white piece.

My problem is trying to create my board class.

My code here:

```
private TextBox[,] textboxes;
public board()
{
    textboxes = new TextBox[,] { 
       {textBox1,textBox2,textBox3,textBox4,textBox5,textBox6,textBox7,textBox8},
       {textBox11,textBox12,textBox13,textBox14,textBox15,textBox16,textBox17,textBox18},
       {textBox21,textBox22,textBox23,textBox24,textBox25,textBox26,textBox27,textBox28},
       {textBox31,textBox32,textBox33,textBox34,textBox35,textBox36,textBox37,textBox38},
       {textBox41,textBox42,textBox43,textBox44,textBox45,textBox46,textBox47,textBox48},
       {textBox51,textBox52,textBox53,textBox54,textBox55,textBox56,textBox57,textBox58},
       {textBox61,textBox62,textBox63,textBox64,textBox65,textBox66,textBox67,textBox68},
       {textBox71,textBox72,textBox73,textBox74,textBox75,textBox76,textBox77,textBox78}};
}
```

This creates an 8x8 grid of boxes. I have this in a class named board. It won't let me use these textboxes here.

I get this **error: Error 1 Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' via nested type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.board'**

Any thoughts or ideas how to make this easier then I am doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously writing out the text boxes like that is not a good choice =)

The choices are:

- Create a `PictureBox` and handle its `Paint` event and draw on it using .NET's powerful `Graphics` object; you get very cool methods such as `DrawRectangle()` and `DrawEllipse()`.  Example snippet:

  ```
  int GridHeight = 50, GridWidth = 50;
  // draw the graph grid                
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
          g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, i * GridWidth, j * GridHeight, GridWidth, GridHeight);
  ```

  That way you can easily modify the size of the board at a higher level.
- If you must go with text boxes, which might be easier to implement interaction with, you need to create them dynamically in the same nested-`for` manner above, though you create `TextBox`es on the fly, such as:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      {
          TextBox cell = new TextBox();
          cell.Top = i * GridHeight;
          cell.Left = j * GridWidth;
          cell.Click += new EventHandler(Cell_Click);
          AllCells.Add(cell);
      }
  ```

  And handle the `Cell_Click` event accordingly.

Comment: Is AllCells a list you defined? also is g in you first example one of those Graphics objects? Sorry, learning new things here.

Comment: @Lewis Cutter IIi; presumably, yes.

Comment: Would this list lok like List<TextBox> AllCell = new List<TextBox>();

Answer (score 1):

I Don't think using textbox is a good idea. But I'm lack of this kind of experience.
So.... I can only give you some procedural advice.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    class Board
    {
        private TextBox[,] textboxes;

        public Board(Form1 form)
        {
            textboxes = new TextBox[,] 
            {
                {form.textBox1, form.textBox2, ....}
            };
        }
    }
}
```